# Cloning a repository with a bash script on macOS

Tags: bash, git

I've written a bash script that loops over a JSON array containing the SSH URL's and clones the repository to a temporary folder.

This is what the bash script looks like:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /Users/schotsl/.ssh/id_ed25519

jq -c '.[]' ./../repos.json | while read i; do
    git clone $i
done
```

But when I run the bash script this is the resulting output:

```
Cloning into 'krijn-text-4.git"'...
"git@codebasehq.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**EDIT:**

I should have clarified this before, to make sure the keys we're correct I regenerated my keys. Now when I run the clone command without the keys added to my SSH agent I get the same error as expected. After adding the keys using this command:

```
ssh-add /Users/schotsl/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I can download the repo just fine, but somehow the script can't?

Comment: This appears to be an `ssh` issue, independent of how you get the URL to clone. Are you sure you added the correct key to the agent and have added the corresponding public key to the repository server?

Comment: Sorry I've expanded on your answer to clarify, I also copied the remote URL from the same JSON file as the script does @chepner

Comment: What does the JSON actually look like?

Comment: Ah: just noticed the trailing `"` in the Git output. You probably need something like `jq -cr` to output raw text, rather than JSON strings, but it would still help to show the JSON you are using to be sure.

Comment: echo the `i` variable in the loop jst to confirm the repository is correct

Comment: Yes thank you! I don't think I can mark your comment as an answer? The issue was indeed the JSON formatting, changing `-c` to `-cr` solves the problem @chepner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `jq` filter was outputting JSON strings like

```
"git@codebasehq.com:/path/to/krijn-text-4.git"
```

when you needed a raw string suitable for use by `ssh`; notice that the host was `"git@codebasehq.com`, not `git@codebasehq.com`.

Use the `-r` option for raw output.

```
jq -cr '.[]' ./../repos.json | while IFS= read -r i; do
  git clone "$i"
done
```